# Pseudo-random Lognormal values

Tags: algorithm, random, logarithm

I'm trying to generate pairs of random values from two lognormal distributions - the catch is that one of them must be less than the other. For example:

```
a1 <- log(47.31)
b1 <- sqrt(2*log(50.84/47.31))
a2 <- log(47.31)
b2 <- sqrt(2*log(59.34/47.31))

x1 <- rlnorm(1,a1,b1)
x2 <- rlnorm(1,a2,b2)
```

I need some way of ensuring that x1 < x2. Is there any slick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no.  The simplest way is to check if the condition is met, and if not, regenerate the randoms.  But the result of this is your variables are no longer characterized by the statistical distributions you started with: the filtering process biases x1 low and x2 high.  But if you're okay with this, then just loop until the desired condition is met... in theory this could take an infinite number of iterations, but I assume you're not that unlucky :).

If the two distributions are the same, it's simpler: just swap them if x1 > x2 (I assume they're not equal!)

Comment: hat's what I was afraid of. I have been using a loop, but this step is in the middle of a simulation, so over 60000 iterations it gets pretty slow. Thanks, though :)

Comment: Yes -- hopefully the two distributions are such that x1 < x2 is reasonably likely.  Additionally, it'd be a big mistake to just regenerate either x1 or x2; that would bias the result, so you need to regenerate both every time x2 > x1.

Comment: Actually, you could do better... if you analytically determined the cumulative probability distribution for x1, then you could pick x1 first using that, then pick x2 using it's original probability distribution until x2 > x1... or analytically determine the conditional probability distribution for x2 given x1...but these may be non-normal.  Generally better to let the computer run a bit longer than to spend too much time doing error-prone calculus!

Comment: Okay, last comment (I promise!)  I tried to calculate the constrained probabilities analytically and, not surprisingly, got an integral of an error function, so that was it for my integration skills.  I did a numerical calculation and the profiles, while nearly normal, are still not truly normal.  If the probability of the constraint is very low, an analytic approximation would need to be made, but in your example that's not necessary.  My example: http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/2261/conditionalprobability.png

Comment: Thanks for the advice djconnol - don't need to go quite that ind-depth, but I appreciate it. I did take your advice on re-generating both x1 and x2 if x2>x1 - didn't think about that biasing the result.